# Show that $e^{A}$ makes sense, $A$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, matrix-equations

I have to solve:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix. The exponential of $A$ is defined as
$$
e^{A}:=I+A+\frac{A^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{A^{3}}{3 !}+\cdots
$$
provided each entry of the matrix converges.

1. Show that $e^{A}$ makes sense
2. and $P$ is an invertible matrix show that $P e^{A} P^{-1}$ is also an exponential matrix.

I have solved Part (2) as :
This follows by noting that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(T B T^{-1}\right)^{k} &=\left(T B T^{-1}\right)\left(T B T^{-1}\right) \cdots\left(T B T^{-1}\right) \\
&=T B\left(T^{-1} T\right) B\left(T^{-1} T\right) \cdots\left(T^{-1} T\right) B T^{-1} \\
&=T B^{k} T^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

then yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{P^{-1} A P} &=I+P^{-1} A P+\frac{\left(P^{-1} A P\right)^{2}}{2 !}+\cdots \\
&=I+P^{-1} A P+P^{-1} \frac{A^{2}}{2 !} P+\cdots \\
&=P^{-1}\left(I+A+\frac{A^{2}}{2 !}+\cdots\right) P=P^{-1} e^{A} P
\end{aligned}
$$

- I don't know how to solve part (1) i.e Show that $e^{A}$ makes sense ?

Comment: Have you been introduced to the operator norm, or any norm on matrices?

Comment: @preferred_anon yes I know about norms on matrices

Answer (score 3):

As Keshav notes, you can prove that the definition of the exponential makes sense as long as you can show that the infinite series converges for any $A$. The obvious way to do this is to compare it to the exponential series for real numbers, which you presumably already know converges.

For a matrix $A$, denote by $|A|$ the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) of $A$. This has the property that $|A^k| \le |A|^k$. Therefore, if we take a finite sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^N \left|A^i/i!\right| \le \sum_{i=0}^N|A|^i/i! \to e^{|A|}$$
so that the sum converges absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 means to ask that you show the series actually converges for any A. (I always see this done after the exponential is introduced, using absolute convergence.)

Comment: exponential of a matrix is not introduced to us, the definition is just given in the question, can you tell me how to show convergence if this is what asked in the question?

Comment: The definition you gave is the only definition I know. You can show this is (absolutely) convergent under any matrix norm using the fact that the taylor series of the regular exponential $e^x$ converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.